# Cannot update or find iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am having problems using port 110 for downloading email.  (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
telnet server.co.uk 110
```

produces

```
Connecting to server.co.uk ...
Could not open connection to the host, on port 110: Connect failed
```

In the control panel at IONOS port 110 is open

If I telnet to a completely different server 110 connects OK, so it is not the ISP blocking the port.

I’ve followed the rules here:
https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/configure-iptables-ubuntu/
and here:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-14-how-to-allow-pop3-serverprotocol-request.html . But, without success.

If I `cd /etc/iptables`, I get the error:

```
/etc/iptables/:  No such file or directory
```

Yet if I `sudo iptables -L` then I get the expected print out:

```
chris@server:/etc$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             Server.co.uk    tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:pop3 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any ideas please to help?

edit from here 26/10/2020

Thank you Doug Smythies and waltinator for your comments and apologies for breaking a convention..

Here is the detail of line by line what I did and the results:

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 77.77.77.777 --sport 110 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

in place of the 77.77.77.777 I used the sever’s IP address and on another occasion the domain

In each case I got this:
a blank line
this would normally indicate to me that the the instruction has worked

Telnet from a cmd terminal provides
Connecting to 77.77.77.777 . . . Could not open connection to the host, on port 110: Connect failed.

I have tried connecting to another (Ubnutu 14 Server) and it connects fine giving me +OK Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready which is what I would expect.

Thanks to you both for your time.

CHRIS

Comment: Your iptables rule set is NOT the reason you can not access port 110, as it is not blocking it. `/etc/iptables` is merely used by convention. For example I don't use it and also don't have that directory, but I use iptables.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Sorry to have broken convention.  I have added to the original question to show exactly what I did.  Still can't open Port 110.